# How do you return a message if no entries are found?

Tags: entries, templating, forloop

I thought this would be very easy but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

How do you output a warning/message if there are no entries to loop through?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(5).find() %}

{% if entries|length %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
      {# Do Loop #}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No entries found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Or am I just sleepy and approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **for** tag has an **else** clause by which you can render a replacement block if no iteration took place because the sequence was empty.

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% else %}
        <li><em>no user found</em></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

reference: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-else-clause

Comment: I thought I had, I think my internet connection glitched when I did. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Oh, wait... No. I can do it in 14 hours :P